# How to convert from java.util.TimeZone to EWS Java API's TimeZoneDefinition?

Tags: java, timezone, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

Given a instance of Java's TimeZone class, how do I convert to Microsoft EWS JAva API's `microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.time.TimeZoneDefinition` ? Specifically, I am using to setStartTimeZone and setEndTimeZone of an appointment in Exchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I found it in their new 2.0 API:

```
import java.util.TimeZone

import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.time.{OlsonTimeZoneDefinition, TimeZoneDefinition}

implicit def javaToEwsTimeZone(tz: TimeZone): TimeZoneDefinition = new OlsonTimeZoneDefinition(tz)
```